# How can I add a watermark in a captured video on iOS - Swift Programming

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, video, watermark

Can someone please help me in adding watermark to the recorded video using Swift programming language. For reference I'm working on AVFoundation framework.

Below are two requirements,

1. Watermark using UILabel as text
2. Watermark using UIImage

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: i have posted the answer. I did not find any solution in particular for Swift programming.

Answer (score 5):

I have found the solution and updating the answer given by @m177312 Check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15933611/1630208)

```
import UIKit
import AssetsLibrary
import AVFoundation

enum QUWatermarkPosition {
    case TopLeft
    case TopRight
    case BottomLeft
    case BottomRight
    case Default
}

class QUWatermarkManager: NSObject {

    func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, watermarkText text : String, saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : QUWatermarkPosition, completion : ((status : AVAssetExportSessionStatus!, session: AVAssetExportSession!, outputURL : NSURL!) -> ())?) {
        self.watermark(video: videoAsset, watermarkText: text, imageName: nil, saveToLibrary: flag, watermarkPosition: position) { (status, session, outputURL) -> () in
            completion!(status: status, session: session, outputURL: outputURL)
        }
    }

    func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, imageName name : String, saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : QUWatermarkPosition, completion : ((status : AVAssetExportSessionStatus!, session: AVAssetExportSession!, outputURL : NSURL!) -> ())?) {
        self.watermark(video: videoAsset, watermarkText: nil, imageName: name, saveToLibrary: flag, watermarkPosition: position) { (status, session, outputURL) -> () in
            completion!(status: status, session: session, outputURL: outputURL)
        }
    }

    private func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, watermarkText text : String!, imageName name : String!, saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : QUWatermarkPosition, completion : ((status : AVAssetExportSessionStatus!, session: AVAssetExportSession!, outputURL : NSURL!) -> ())?) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
            // 1 - Create AVMutableComposition object. This object will hold your AVMutableCompositionTrack instances.
            var mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

            // 2 - Create video tracks
            var compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
            var clipVideoTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as! AVAssetTrack
            compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), ofTrack: clipVideoTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero, error: nil)
            clipVideoTrack.preferredTransform

            // Video size
            let videoSize = clipVideoTrack.naturalSize

            // sorts the layer in proper order and add title layer
            var parentLayer = CALayer()
            var videoLayer = CALayer()
            parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height)
            videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height)
            parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)

            if text != nil {
                // Adding watermark text
                var titleLayer = CATextLayer()
                titleLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
                titleLayer.string = text
                titleLayer.font = "Helvetica"
                titleLayer.fontSize = 15
                titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
                titleLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height)
                parentLayer.addSublayer(titleLayer)

                println("\(videoSize.width)")
                println("\(videoSize.height)")
            } else if name != nil {
                // Adding image 
                var watermarkImage = UIImage(named: name)
                var imageLayer = CALayer()
                imageLayer.contents = watermarkImage?.CGImage

                var xPosition : CGFloat = 0.0
                var yPosition : CGFloat = 0.0
                let imageSize : CGFloat = 57.0

                switch (position) {
                case .TopLeft:
                    xPosition = 0
                    yPosition = 0
                    break
                case .TopRight:
                    xPosition = videoSize.width - imageSize
                    yPosition = 0
                    break
                case .BottomLeft:
                    xPosition = 0
                    yPosition = videoSize.height - imageSize
                    break
                case .BottomRight, .Default:
                    xPosition = videoSize.width - imageSize
                    yPosition = videoSize.height - imageSize
                    break
                default:
                    break
                }

                println("\(xPosition)")
                println("\(yPosition)")

                imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, imageSize, imageSize)
                imageLayer.opacity = 0.65
                parentLayer.addSublayer(imageLayer)
            }

            var videoComp = AVMutableVideoComposition()
            videoComp.renderSize = videoSize
            videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
            videoComp.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, inLayer: parentLayer)

            /// instruction
            var instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
            instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, mixComposition.duration)
            var videoTrack = mixComposition.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as! AVAssetTrack

            let layerInstruction = self.videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(compositionVideoTrack, asset: videoAsset)

            //var layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)

            instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
            videoComp.instructions = [instruction]

            // 4 - Get path
            let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
            var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .LongStyle
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
            let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
            let savePath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("watermarkVideo-\(date).mov")
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: savePath)

            // 5 - Create Exporter
            let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
            exporter.outputURL = url
            exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
            exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
            exporter.videoComposition = videoComp

            // 6 - Perform the Export
            exporter.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler() {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    if exporter.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed {
                        let outputURL = exporter.outputURL
                        if flag {
                            // Save to library
                            let library = ALAssetsLibrary()
                            if library.videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL) {
                                library.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL,
                                    completionBlock: { (assetURL:NSURL!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                                        completion!(status: AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed, session: exporter, outputURL: outputURL)
                                })
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Dont svae to library
                            completion!(status: AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed, session: exporter, outputURL: outputURL)
                        }

                    } else {
                        // Error
                        completion!(status: exporter.status, session: exporter, outputURL: nil)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }


    private func orientationFromTransform(transform: CGAffineTransform) -> (orientation: UIImageOrientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
        var assetOrientation = UIImageOrientation.Up
        var isPortrait = false
        if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .Right
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .Left
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .Up
        } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .Down
        }
        return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
    }

    private func videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
        let assetTrack = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as! AVAssetTrack

        var transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
        let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform)

        var scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.width
        if assetInfo.isPortrait {
            scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
            let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleToFitRatio, scaleToFitRatio)
            instruction.setTransform(CGAffineTransformConcat(assetTrack.preferredTransform, scaleFactor),
                atTime: kCMTimeZero)
        } else {
            let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleToFitRatio, scaleToFitRatio)
            var concat = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(assetTrack.preferredTransform, scaleFactor), CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 2))
            if assetInfo.orientation == .Down {
                let fixUpsideDown = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
                let windowBounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
                let yFix = assetTrack.naturalSize.height + windowBounds.height
                let centerFix = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(assetTrack.naturalSize.width, yFix)
                concat = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(fixUpsideDown, centerFix), scaleFactor)
            }
            instruction.setTransform(concat, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
        }

        return instruction
    }
}
```

Thanks to many people who have helped me on StackOverflow. I have taken many references from stack overflow if i did not tag anyone whose answer is here, i apologies to them. And Thank you for helping me out. Hope this answer will be helpful to everyone.

Comment: was the watermark as sharp as the original image or was there some pixelation?

Comment: Am having doubt in this . Can u help me ?

       @IBAction func addButAcn(sender: UIButton) {
        
        let videoAssets = AVAsset(URL: mediaURL)
        
        QUWatermarkManager.shared.watermark(video: videoAssets, watermarkText: "My First Try", saveToLibrary: true, watermarkPosition: QUWatermarkPosition.TopRight) { (status, session, outputURL) in
            
            print("\n\n Statuss      ",  status )
            print("session      ",  session )
            print("outputURL      ",  outputURL )
         }
         }

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Ankit-Jain in

Swift 3:

```
import UIKit
import AssetsLibrary
import AVFoundation
import Photos

enum QUWatermarkPosition {
    case TopLeft
    case TopRight
    case BottomLeft
    case BottomRight
    case Default
}

class QUWatermarkManager: NSObject {

    func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, watermarkText text : String, saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : QUWatermarkPosition, completion : ((_ status : AVAssetExportSessionStatus?, _ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?) {
        self.watermark(video: videoAsset, watermarkText: text, imageName: nil, saveToLibrary: flag, watermarkPosition: position) { (status, session, outputURL) -> () in
            completion!(status, session, outputURL)
        }
    }

    func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, imageName name : String, saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : QUWatermarkPosition, completion : ((_ status : AVAssetExportSessionStatus?, _ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?) {
        self.watermark(video: videoAsset, watermarkText: nil, imageName: name, saveToLibrary: flag, watermarkPosition: position) { (status, session, outputURL) -> () in
            completion!(status, session, outputURL)
        }
    }

    private func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, watermarkText text : String!, imageName name : String!, saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : QUWatermarkPosition, completion : ((_ status : AVAssetExportSessionStatus?, _ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {

            let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

            let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
            let clipVideoTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
            do {
                try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: clipVideoTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            let videoSize = clipVideoTrack.naturalSize

            let parentLayer = CALayer()
            let videoLayer = CALayer()
            parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
            videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
            parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)

            if text != nil {
                let titleLayer = CATextLayer()
                titleLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                titleLayer.string = text
                titleLayer.font = "Helvetica" as CFTypeRef
                titleLayer.fontSize = 15
                titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
                titleLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
                parentLayer.addSublayer(titleLayer)
            } else if name != nil {
                let watermarkImage = UIImage(named: name)
                let imageLayer = CALayer()
                imageLayer.contents = watermarkImage?.cgImage

                var xPosition : CGFloat = 0.0
                var yPosition : CGFloat = 0.0
                let imageSize : CGFloat = 57.0

                switch (position) {
                case .TopLeft:
                    xPosition = 0
                    yPosition = 0
                    break
                case .TopRight:
                    xPosition = videoSize.width - imageSize
                    yPosition = 0
                    break
                case .BottomLeft:
                    xPosition = 0
                    yPosition = videoSize.height - imageSize
                    break
                case .BottomRight, .Default:
                    xPosition = videoSize.width - imageSize
                    yPosition = videoSize.height - imageSize
                    break
                }


                imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
                imageLayer.opacity = 0.65
                parentLayer.addSublayer(imageLayer)
            }

            let videoComp = AVMutableVideoComposition()
            videoComp.renderSize = videoSize
            videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
            videoComp.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)

            let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
            instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, mixComposition.duration)
            _ = mixComposition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as AVAssetTrack

            let layerInstruction = self.videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: compositionVideoTrack, asset: videoAsset)

            instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
            videoComp.instructions = [instruction]

            let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] 
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
            let date = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory).appendingPathComponent("watermarkVideo-\(date).mov")

            let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
            exporter?.outputURL = url
            exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
            exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
            exporter?.videoComposition = videoComp

            exporter?.exportAsynchronously() {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    if exporter?.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed {
                        let outputURL = exporter?.outputURL
                        if flag {
                            // Save to library
//                            let library = ALAssetsLibrary()

                            if UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL!.path) {
                                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: outputURL!)
                                }) { saved, error in
                                    if saved {
                                        completion!(AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed, exporter, outputURL)
                                    }
                                }
                            }

//                            if library.videoAtPathIs(compatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum: outputURL) {
//                                library.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL,
//                                                                           completionBlock: { (assetURL:NSURL!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
//                                                                            
//                                                                            completion!(AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed, exporter, outputURL)
//                                })
//                            }
                        } else {
                            completion!(AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed, exporter, outputURL)
                        }

                    } else {
                        // Error
                        completion!(exporter?.status, exporter, nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private func orientationFromTransform(transform: CGAffineTransform) -> (orientation: UIImageOrientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
        var assetOrientation = UIImageOrientation.up
        var isPortrait = false
        if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .right
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .left
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .up
        } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .down
        }
        return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
    }

    private func videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
        let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

        let transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
        let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform: transform)

        var scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.width
        if assetInfo.isPortrait {
            scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
            let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
            instruction.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor),
                                     at: kCMTimeZero)
        } else {
            let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
            var concat = assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2))
            if assetInfo.orientation == .down {
                let fixUpsideDown = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
                let windowBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
                let yFix = assetTrack.naturalSize.height + windowBounds.height
                let centerFix = CGAffineTransform(translationX: assetTrack.naturalSize.width, y: yFix)
                concat = fixUpsideDown.concatenating(centerFix).concatenating(scaleFactor)
            }
            instruction.setTransform(concat, at: kCMTimeZero)
        }

        return instruction
    }
}
```